# Finding the string from the list of array objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
TA.ServiceProxy.RoleManagement.GetSubPrivilagesResponses subPrivilagesResponses = GetSubPrivilagesFromPrivilageCodeStatic("Authoring01");
if (subPrivilagesResponses != null && subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList != null)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList.Length; j++)
    {
       if (subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList[j].PrivilageCode == "CREATOR")
       {
           objTemplate.IsTagged = true;
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

The above code is written as

```
TA.ServiceProxy.RoleManagement.GetSubPrivilagesResponses subPrivilagesResponses = GetSubPrivilagesFromPrivilageCodeStatic("Authoring01");
if (subPrivilagesResponses != null && subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList != null)
{
   var item = subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList.SingleOrDefault(cd => cd.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR");
    if(item != null && item.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR")
        objTemplate.IsTagged = true;                              
}
```

In what are the different way it can be modified in order to boost performance and efficiency by making use of Lambda or LINQ

Comment: The first version finds the first of possible more items having `PrivilageCode == "CREATOR"`, while the second actually ensures that there is only one (or none) item having that predicate - if more items satisfy the condition a `ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException` exception is thrown. So they are not doing the exact same thing. Which one is the correct/preferred?

Comment: Good Catch. It will always be only one or none. Apart from `SingleOrDefault`. What are all possible ways to match `PrivilageCode == "CREATOR"`. I mean to say how can the above snippet can be rewritten in different possible ways to yield the above condition. Even I or the readers would benefit a lot @HenrikHansen

Comment: do you actually have any performance issue with the current code ? if yes, then please explain what is the issue, and where it happens. (include any code if any).

Answer (score 5):

Because the question is about **performance** and **efficiency** that's why some sort of benchmarking would be essential to compare different implementations. I have found [BenckmarkDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/) really useful for these kind of experiments.

You can define the for loop version as your **baseline** and the tool will compare the other implementation against that. Here is my simplified example how to setup your environment for measurement:

```
[HtmlExporter]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.RunStrategy.ColdStart, targetCount: 100)]
public class IterationOptimalizationExperiment
{
    private static List<Data> target;
    private const string TheOne = "TheOne";

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        target = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
            .Select(i => new Data { Id = i, Type = i % 7777 == 0 ? TheOne : "NotTheOne" })
            .ToList();
    }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void WithFor()
    {
        bool hasFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Count; i++)
            if (string.Equals(target[i].Type, TheOne, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                hasFound = true;
                break;
            }

    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void WithForEach()
    {
        bool hasFound = false;
        foreach (var t in target)
            if (string.Equals(t.Type, TheOne, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                hasFound = true;
                break;
            }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void WithAny()
    {
        bool hasFound = target.Any(t => string.Equals(t.Type, TheOne, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

And you should simply call the following command to start your experiment: `BenchmarkRunner.Run<IterationOptimalizationExperiment>();`

When you run it in Release mode it will dump something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C#6 or above, you can use the [null conditional operator `?.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
var hasCreator = GetSubPrivilagesFromPrivilageCodeStatic("Authoring01")?.SubprivilagesList?.Any(cd => cd.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR") ?? false;
if (hasCreator) 
{
    objTemplate.IsTagged = true;
}
```

If it's not too late, I'd correct the spelling of privilege in your code. I misspelt latitude (as lattitude) in some key js once and frustrated my colleagues for years.

Comment: you could inline it with  `objTemplate.IsTagged` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The only think that comes to my mind is to rewrite this:

```cs
var item = subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList.SingleOrDefault(cd => cd.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR");
    if(item != null && item.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR")
        objTemplate.IsTagged = true;
```

into this:

```cs
if (subPrivilagesResponses.SubprivilagesList.Any(cd => cd.PrivilageCode == "CREATOR"))
        objTemplate.IsTagged = true;
```

Comment: You could set `objTemplate.IsTagged` to equal `...Any()` directly instead of the `if`-statement.